# i don't know what happened

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I get:
Error: Class App\Entity\User contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

> (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUsername)

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface; 
    use App\Entity\Role; 
    /**  
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")  
    */ 
    class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {     
    /**      
    * @ORM\Id()      
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue()      
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")..
```

I need to create a register form.

Comment: Try to not write "I don't know what happened" as your problem title and instead have a concise explanation of your problem.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory and I strongly encourage you to read the whole [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the asking section  before make your next question.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing UserInterface so you have to implements all method associated.
In your case you have an error with getUsername so add it to your entity :

```
public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}
public function setUsername(string $username): void
{
    $this->username = $username;
}
```

You may have other method to implement ([see demo](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/src/Entity/User.php)) such as :

```
public function setFullName(string $fullName): void
{
    $this->fullName = $fullName;
}
public function getFullName(): ?string
{
    return $this->fullName;
}
public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}
public function setEmail(string $email): void
{
    $this->email = $email;
}
public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}
public function setPassword(string $password): void
{
    $this->password = $password;
}
/**
 * Returns the roles or permissions granted to the user for security.
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantees that a user always has at least one role for security
    if (empty($roles)) {
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    }
    return array_unique($roles);
}
public function setRoles(array $roles): void
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
}
/**
 * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getSalt(): ?string
{
    // See "Do you need to use a Salt?" at https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html
    // we're using bcrypt in security.yml to encode the password, so
    // the salt value is built-in and you don't have to generate one
    return null;
}
/**
 * Removes sensitive data from the user.
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function eraseCredentials(): void
{
    // if you had a plainPassword property, you'd nullify it here
    // $this->plainPassword = null;
}
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function serialize(): string
{
    // add $this->salt too if you don't use Bcrypt or Argon2i
    return serialize([$this->id, $this->username, $this->password]);
}
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function unserialize($serialized): void
{
    // add $this->salt too if you don't use Bcrypt or Argon2i
    [$this->id, $this->username, $this->password] = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
}
```

Comment: If it was the proper answer to your question close the post by putting this post as the answer.